# Mage registry key "_singleton/VladimirPopov_WebForms_Model_Observer" already exists

Tags: magento, registry, key, mage

I have uninstalled web from extension and installed it again since than I am getting this error while i try to open the admin. Front end is working fine.Please help

Comment: Hey,
My guess is that you did not uninstall it fully.
So it is trying to load a Singleton twice.

That or something is misconfigured in the Modules .xml files.

Take a look and try to clean it up.

Comment: i have checked everything and also deleted the xml file of this extension in module folder

Answer (score 3):

It is very important to clear the Compiler cache and after that turn it on in backend of Magento.

Clear the cache:

```
SSH:
find ./var/cache -type f -delete
FTP: 
mrm -r ./var/cache ; mkdir ./var/cache
```

Disable/Clear Magento compilation

```
SSH:
php -f shell/compiler.php -- disable
php -f shell/compiler.php -- clear
FTP:
mv ./includes ./includes.unused
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so Debug.
Go to app/Mage.php. Find register function add in

```
if ($key == '_singleton/VladimirPopov_WebForms_Model_Observer'){
    Mage::log(debug_backtrace(false), null, 'backtrace.log');
}
```

Do this right before `if (isset(self::$_registry[$key])) {`

Then go to app/var/log/some_filename.log. There should be two entries. One is right and one is wrong (read duplicate). That should help you to find the offending file/function.

**NOTE: Be sure to backup app/Mage first and restore it after. This is a critical file.**

Comment: I have the file bit did not understand what do you mean by (read duplicate).is there any way to send you the file

Comment: Just pick an uploading site and drop the link.

Comment: Oops, I edited my command.
Way too much info in that log.
You should probably delete it.
Replace with the new one.

Comment: after putting the code you have asked and again installing the extension I am getting this error."Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://magento-36664-riki.vpsapps.net/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/e365a503d56c8f0877f4f6420476a942/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly."