# Mage registry key "_singleton/opc/observer" already exists

Tags: magento, checkout, onepage-checkout

I am using Magento version 1.9.2 with Porto theme. My site is running and working.
But i installed onepage checkout plugin (IWD checkout suite- free version). After installing , I got this error in magento backend.

```
Mage registry key "_singleton/opc/observer" already exists
```

[image: Magento backend error image]

I tried deactivating plugin from file system but same error is coming.

Note: I have installed another magento without any porto theme and IWD checkout suite is working perfectly there.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem now, try this:

Go to app/Mage.php

Find `register` function add in

```
if ($key == '_singleton/opc/observer'){
    Mage::log(debug_backtrace(false), null, 'backtrace.log');
}
```

Do this right before `if (isset(self::$_registry[$key])) {`

Then go to `app/var/log/some_filename.log`. There should be two entries. One is right and one is wrong (read duplicate). That should help you to find the offending file/function.

[Mage registry key "_singleton/VladimirPopov_WebForms_Model_Observer" already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001086/mage-registry-key-singleton-vladimirpopov-webforms-model-observer-already-exi)